# stack smashing detected combining ROS2 node an gzclient

Tags: ros2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a simple node that listens to Gazebo transport messages and republishes them on ROS2.

When I try to run the client/node I get the following error (Backtrace at the end of the message)

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

The reason I suspect Gazebo is that the stack smash only happens when I actually start the gz server. Also, while the backtrace points at the FastRTPS XML loading code, if I spin the ROS node and then start the gz server, it will crash after I start the server.

I've created the following stub code to test. If you remove the allocation of std::shared_ptr bridge it will not crash. This code will only crash if the gzserver is running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp>

#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>

#include <gazebo/gazebo_client.hh>

class GazeboRealSenseBridge : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    GazeboRealSenseBridge() : rclcpp::Node("gazebo_realsense_bridge")
    {
        publisher = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>("realsense_pointcloud");



    }

private:
    rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr publisher;


};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    gazebo::client::setup(0, nullptr);


    std::shared_ptr<GazeboRealSenseBridge> bridge = std::make_shared<GazeboRealSenseBridge>();

    std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> > messageTypesAndTopics = gazebo::transport::getAdvertisedTopics();
    for(auto it = messageTypesAndTopics.begin(); it != messageTypesAndTopics.end(); it++)
    {
        for(auto topicIt = it->second.begin(); topicIt != it->second.end(); topicIt++)
        {
            std::cout << *topicIt << " (" << it->first << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }



    gazebo::client::shutdown();
//    rclcpp::spin(bridge);
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

## Appendix - Backtrace

I think this backtrace is suspect, as it will show the same backtrace if you spin the ros node and start the server later. This code should not continuously run.

```
Thread 1 "gazebo-realsens" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51 51      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory. (gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff6178f5d in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007ffff61c128d in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff62e6a26 "*** %s
***: %s terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff6267811 in __GI___fortify_fail_abort (need_backtrace=need_backtrace@entry=false, msg=msg@entry=0x7ffff62e6a0e "stack smashing detected") at fortify_fail.c:33
#4  0x00007ffff62677d2 in __stack_chk_fail () at stack_chk_fail.c:29
#5  0x00007ffff38b4031 in eprosima::fastrtps::xmlparser::XMLParser::loadXML (filename=<error reading variable: Cannot create a lazy string with address 0x0, and a non-zero length.>, Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> expected string or bytes-like object:  root=) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp/xmlparser/XMLParser.cpp:228
#6  0x00007ffff38be3fc in eprosima::fastrtps::xmlparser::XMLProfileManager::loadXMLFile (filename=<error reading variable: Cannot create a lazy string with address 0x0, and a non-zero length.>) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp/xmlparser/XMLProfileManager.cpp:105
#7  0x00007ffff38bee68 in eprosima::fastrtps::xmlparser::XMLProfileManager::loadDefaultXMLFile () at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp/xmlparser/XMLProfileManager.cpp:86
#8  0x00007ffff3814fcb in eprosima::fastrtps::Domain::getDefaultParticipantAttributes (participant_attributes=...) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/src/cpp/Domain.cpp:159
#9  0x00007ffff5d12e00 in rmw_create_node (name=name@entry=0x5555559b51b0 "gazebo_realsense_bridge", namespace_=namespace_@entry=0x7ffff7bccdc4 "/", domain_id=domain_id@entry=0, security_options=security_options@entry=0x7fffffffd120)
    at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/rmw_fastrtps_cpp/src/rmw_node.cpp:209
#10 0x00007ffff7bc1ba5 in rcl_node_init (node=node@entry=0x5555559b5310, name=0x5555559b51b0 "gazebo_realsense_bridge", namespace_=<optimized out>, options=options@entry=0x7fffffffd350) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/ros2/rcl/rcl/src/rcl/node.c:274
#11 0x00007ffff794dbac in rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBase::NodeBase (this=0x5555559b5250, node_name="gazebo_realsense_bridge", namespace_="", context=...) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node_interfaces/node_base.cpp:90
#12 0x00007ffff794c0d4 in rclcpp::Node::Node (this=0x5555559aaa30, node_name="gazebo_realsense_bridge", namespace_="", context=..., use_intra_process_comms=<optimized out>) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp:54
#13 0x00007ffff794cb7a in rclcpp::Node::Node (this=0x5555559aaa30, node_name="gazebo_realsense_bridge", namespace_="", use_intra_process_comms=<optimized out>) at /home/rosbuild/ci_scripts/ws/src/ros2/rclcpp/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/node.cpp:46
#14 0x000055555555e330 in GazeboRealSenseBridge::GazeboRealSenseBridge (this=0x5555559aaa30) at /home/jesper/git/halodi/halodi_ros_ws/src/halodi-gazebo-sensors/gazebo_realsense_bridge/src/gazebo_realsense_bridge.cpp:15
#15 0x000055555556626e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>::construct<GazeboRealSenseBridge> (this=0x7fffffffd777,
__p=0x5555559aaa30) at /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136
#16 0x0000555555565973 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>
>::construct<GazeboRealSenseBridge> (__a=..., __p=0x5555559aaa30) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:475
#17 0x0000555555564b99 in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<GazeboRealSenseBridge, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<>(std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>) (this=0x5555559aaa20, __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:526
#18 0x0000555555563a72 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<GazeboRealSenseBridge, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, GazeboRealSenseBridge*, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge> const&) (this=0x7fffffffd8f8, __a=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:637
#19 0x00005555555629b2 in std::__shared_ptr<GazeboRealSenseBridge, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge> const&) (this=0x7fffffffd8f0,
__tag=..., __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1295
#20 0x000055555556164a in std::shared_ptr<GazeboRealSenseBridge>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge> const&) (this=0x7fffffffd8f0,
__tag=..., __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:344
#21 0x00005555555604e5 in std::allocate_shared<GazeboRealSenseBridge, std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge>>(std::allocator<GazeboRealSenseBridge> const&) (__a=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:691
#22 0x000055555555f339 in std::make_shared<GazeboRealSenseBridge> () at /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:707
#23 0x000055555555c465 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffda08) at /home/jesper/git/halodi/halodi_ros_ws/src/halodi-gazebo-sensors/gazebo_realsense_bridge/src/gazebo_realsense_bridge.cpp:35
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18977/stack-smashing-detected-combining-ros2-node-an-gzclient/) by [JesperSmith](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4947/jespersmith/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My bad. Recompiling ROS2 from source fixed the issue.

---

Originally posted by [JesperSmith](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4947/jespersmith/) with karma: 1 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0